# How to use wcf service as data source for ReportViewer control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, wcf, rdlc

How can I use a web service (WCF) as the data source for a reportviewer .

I create web application in that i want use .rdlc ( dont want .rdl) so i write wcf service .

How to link wcf service into reportviewer to display data in rdlc...

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice article from By John Gathogo in code project 
"Consuming a WCF Service from an SSRS (RDL) Server Report" 
kindly flow the link :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37270/Consuming-a-WCF-Service-from-an-SSRS-RDL-Server-Re

Answer (score -1):

If you are building your report in Visual Studio 2010 then you do Data > Add new Datasource > Service and Create a Service reference for your project.

The service with all the available fields will now show up in your datasource list for the report